# What's this symbol called?

Tags: calculus

[image: Picture]
What is this symbol called and how do you use it?

Comment: See also [THIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertical_bar)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a symbol, I suppose I would call it a "bar".

To pronounce it in this context, I would say "evaluated at" and then whatever the subscript is. So
$$ \frac{dy}{dx} \bigg |_{x_0}$$
might be pronounced "the derivative of $y$ with respect to $x$ evaluated at $x_0$". Others might say that
$$  \frac{dy}{dx} \bigg |_{x_0} = \frac{dy}{dx}(x_0),$$
where the $(x_0)$ is the argument of the function $\frac{dy}{dx}$.

This is essentially the same sign that appears after evaluating integrals, if you have seen that before.